# iOS - How to check on/off status of Flashlight / Torch / Flash

Tags: ios, torch, flashlight, avcapturedevice, camera-flash

I would like to know if the user has turned on the light over the control center before starting the app. I have a whole simple test app with the following code in the `viewDidLoad`.

```
for(AVCaptureDevice *device in [AVCaptureDevice devices]){
        if ([device isTorchAvailable] && [device hasTorch] ){
            NSLog(@"%ld -- %ld -- %@ -- %.2f -- %@", device.torchMode, device.flashMode, device.isFlashActive ? @"yes" : @"no", device.torchLevel, device.isTorchActive ? @"yes" : @"no");
        }
    }
```

The light will turn on and the app will start. But it returns allways:

> 0 -- 0 -- no -- 0.00 -- no

*It says:*

> AVCaptureDevice *device;
>   **device.torchMode** = AVCaptureTorchModeOff
>   **device.flashMode** = AVCaptureFlashModeOff
>   **device.isFlashActive** = NO
>   **device.torchLevel** = 0.0f
>   **device.isTorchActive** = NO

Problem:

I am told "not active" however the flashlight of the Device is ON. It was switched on in the control center. Why can't I grab this information?

Comment: I struggle with the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no update yet. I don't know if it's possible at all. @IvoLeko